# No keypoints detected with ORB

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, feature-extraction

I was using ORB detector (CV2) for feature detection. But it returned no kps with a small `roi` (cropped out by YOLOv3 automatically). I thought the reason was the image being too small, so as I debugged, I cropped out that small `roi` manually and run ORB again, it actually returns a lot of kps...
[image: see here]

So could you please give me some opinions on why the ORB detector can give different results with the identical input image?

the code is really simple, just

```py
kp, des = orb.detectAndCompute(roi, None)
```

Comment: I looked into it again and found out that the "manually cropping" enlarges the picture size [59,80] px by about  5 times. So I guess the size was indeed too small for feature detection... Do you guys have opinions on how to cope with this situatoin?

Comment: There could be many reasons and it's really difficult for people to help you without being able to reproduce your findings. Can you add the image that you're using and turn your quesiton in a minimal, reproducible example (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?